# Web Scraping a List in Python Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, yahoo

I am new at Python and trying to learn how to use BeautifulSoup to scrape a webpage. For starters, I was just using yahoo.com's HTML code:

view-source:https://www.yahoo.com/

I wanted to scrape the list of links starting on row 577 and ending at 633 and get their URL and the title and put it in table in Python.

So far, I have the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myURL = "http://www.yahoo.com"
myPage = requests.get(myURL)

yahoo = BeautifulSoup(myPage.content)

print yahoo.prettify()

YahooList = yahoo.find('ul', class_="Pos(r) Miw(1000px) Pstart(9px) Lh(1.7) Reader-open_Op(0) mini-header_Op(0)")
print YahooList
```

I am unsure of how to proceed further from this. All the examples I am finding are for web scraping from tables but I am not finding much on how to do it on a list.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: What do you mean about *I wanted to scrape the list of links starting on row 577 and ending at 633* ? Do you mean *scrape all the link from the 577 line of the HTML source code, to 633 line* ?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I mean. From the entire webpage, I just want to scrape those specific lines. My apologies if that was unclear in my post.

Comment: Variable names like `myURL, YahooList` are not Pythonic, PEP-8 recommended names would be `my_url`, `yahoo_list` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need *only scrape specific lines*, you need *get these line* before you *scrape it*. I'd suggest use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and a **list slice** to get them.

For example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
>>> print('\n'.join(r.text.splitlines()[575:634]))
```

The output is:

```
<li class="D(b)">
    <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/politics/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:politics;t5:politics;cpos:9;" tabindex="1">Politics</a>
</li>

<li class="D(b)">
    <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/celebrity/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:celebrity;t5:celebrity;cpos:10;" tabindex="1">Celebrity</a>
</li>

...

<li class="D(b)">
    <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/travel/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:travel;t5:travel;cpos:22;" tabindex="1">Travel</a>
</li>

<li class="D(b)">
    <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/autos/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:autos;t5:autos;cpos:23;" tabindex="1">Autos</a>
</li>
```

- `r.text.splitlines()` split the HTML source code by lines, and gives a list.
- `[575:634]` is a list slice, which slices the list, and gives lines from **576** to **634**. I added two more lines because without them, the output will be:

  ```
      <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/politics/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:politics;t5:politics;cpos:9;" tabindex="1">Politics</a>
  </li>

  <li class="D(b)">
      <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/celebrity/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:celebrity;t5:celebrity;cpos:10;" tabindex="1">Celebrity</a>
  </li>

  ...

  <li class="D(b)">
      <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/travel/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:travel;t5:travel;cpos:22;" tabindex="1">Travel</a>
  </li>

  <li class="D(b)">
      <a href="https://www.yahoo.com/autos/" class="D(b) Fz(13px) C($topbarMenu) Py(3px) Td(n) Td(u):h"   data-ylk="slk:autos;t5:autos;cpos:23;" tabindex="1">Autos</a>
  ```

  And which isn't a *valid HTML code block*.
- [`'\n'.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) joins the list by `\n`, and gives another string which you want.

---

After we have the *specific lines* :

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('\n'.join(r.text.splitlines()[575:634]), 'html.parser')
>>> for i in soup.find_all('a'):
...     print(i.get('href'))
...     
... 
https://www.yahoo.com/politics/
https://www.yahoo.com/celebrity/
https://www.yahoo.com/movies/
https://www.yahoo.com/music/
https://www.yahoo.com/tv/
https://www.yahoo.com/health/
https://www.yahoo.com/style/
https://www.yahoo.com/beauty/
https://www.yahoo.com/food/
https://www.yahoo.com/parenting/
https://www.yahoo.com/makers/
https://www.yahoo.com/tech/
https://shopping.yahoo.com/
https://www.yahoo.com/travel/
https://www.yahoo.com/autos/
```

`soup.find_all('a')` finds all the `<a>` HTML tags in the string (HTML code block) we have, and gives a list of these tags.

Then, we use `for` loop over the list, and use `i.get('href')` to get the `href` attribute (the link you want) of the `<a>` tag.

---

You can also use a [**list comprehension**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-in-python-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-us/34835952#34835952) to put the result into a list, rather than print it out:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup('\n'.join(r.text.splitlines()[575:634]), 'html.parser')

l = [i.get('href') for i in soup.find_all('a')]
```

`l` is the list which you're looking for.

---

If you also want get the *title* of these links, you can use `i.text` to get it. However, there's no *table object* in Python, I think you mean [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
>>> d = {i.text: i.get('href') for i in soup.find_all('a')}
>>> pprint(d)
{'Autos': 'https://www.yahoo.com/autos/',
 'Beauty': 'https://www.yahoo.com/beauty/',
 'Celebrity': 'https://www.yahoo.com/celebrity/',
 'Food': 'https://www.yahoo.com/food/',
 'Health': 'https://www.yahoo.com/health/',
 'Makers': 'https://www.yahoo.com/makers/',
 'Movies': 'https://www.yahoo.com/movies/',
 'Music': 'https://www.yahoo.com/music/',
 'Parenting': 'https://www.yahoo.com/parenting/',
 'Politics': 'https://www.yahoo.com/politics/',
 'Shopping': 'https://shopping.yahoo.com/',
 'Style': 'https://www.yahoo.com/style/',
 'TV': 'https://www.yahoo.com/tv/',
 'Tech': 'https://www.yahoo.com/tech/',
 'Travel': 'https://www.yahoo.com/travel/'}
>>> d['TV']
'https://www.yahoo.com/tv/'
>>> d['Food']
'https://www.yahoo.com/food/'
```

So you can use `{i.text: i.get('href') for i in soup.find_all('a')}` to get the dict you want.

In this case, `i.text` (title) is the keys in that dict, for example `'TV'` and `'Food'`.

And `i.get('href')` is the value (links), for example `'https://www.yahoo.com/tv/'` and `'https://www.yahoo.com/food/'`.

You can access the value by `d[key]` as my code above.